# DateTime? Formatting in Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an issue with a datetime format, in asp mvc 4.
The date is displaying as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss,
All I want displayed is dd/mm/yy as it's a DOB.

My model is as follows...

```
[Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}"]
public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
```

And my view...

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Patient.DOB, new { @class = "m-wrap span8", disabled = "disabled" })
```

I do not want the user to be able to edit the date so EditFor is not an option, I have tried to add the tag ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, to the property along with replacing the TextBoxFor with The EditFor , this does format correctly be allows the user to edit !

I've also tried DOB.value.ToShortDateString(), no joy.

Any tips or help are appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You are using [short date format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#ShortDate) which pulls the date/time format of the current thread culture (which by default is usually your OS culture).

If you need it to be a consistent format you need to fix it i.e.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}")]
```

The `DisplayFormat` attribute only works if you use `EditorFor` rather than `TextBoxFor`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that didn't seem to solve it, would the problem be related to the "?" following Datetime ....

Comment: @mkell which mode is your view in edit or display? `?` just means the `DateTime` is nullable this shouldn't affect the formatting.

Comment: Not fully sure I understand what you mean by mode? or where to check?

Comment: @mkell Ignore that statement...I was basically meaning is it an editable field or is it a readonly one (however, your example shows its a textbox) - you need to set the `AllowInEditMode` property to true in the `DisplayFormat` attribute for it to apply to the textbox.

Comment: I believe you mean like this  -- [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)],    still doesn't resolve the problem, thanks for continuing to try though.

Comment: There is no AllowInEditMode available with intellisense

Comment: @mkell think I have sussed it, you need to use `EditorFor` the `DisplayFormat` attribute doesn't work for `TextBoxFor`. And yes, I meant `AllowFormatInEditMode`.

Comment: Not to burst your bubble, yes that formats correctly as I've already tried this, but it allows the user to edit the date being displayed, I need it to be readonly....

Comment: @mkell haha you aren't bursting any bubble - it's up to you to apply attributes to the field so the user *can't* edit it (e.g. via CSS or Javascript). Either that or you just use `DisplayFor` instead of `EditorFor`. Bare in mind though, disabled fields won't post back to the server so I would opt for `DisplayFor`.

Comment: Well played sir, I was thinking of the displayformat in the model rather than DisplayFor in the view, it's looking better, I'm goning to try and format a box around it so it's similar to other fields on the page, many thanks.